# My button of popup page of chrome extension doesn't receive event, what is the error?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

i create a chrome extension for fun, but i have a problem. If i open popup.html by Chrome, the button of this page worked, but when i opened it through my Chrome's Extension, this button didn't work. Can anybody explan for me what is the problem in here, thank you !

Here is code in popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Blank New Tab</title>
<style>
div {
 color: #cccccc;
 vertical-align: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 300%;
     }
 </style>
 <script src="my_popup.js"></script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div style="height:40%"></div>
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td><button onclick="FncZoomIn();" id="btnZoomIn">ZoomIn</button>  </td>
       <td><button onclick="click" id="btnReset">Reset</button>  </td>
       <td><button onclick="click" id="btnZoomOut">ZoomOut</button>  </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

And here is the code in js file

```
function FncZoomIn()
{
window.open("https://www.google.com.vn/");
chrome.tabs.getZoom(1);
}

function FncZoomOut()
{
chrome.tabs.getZoom(-10);
}
```

Comment: Plugins don't allow inline javascript (javascript outside .js files won't work). Try selecting the button by it's ID and adding an onclick event listener to it.

Comment: can you give me an example for it, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Chrome plugins (firefox plugins, and probably all other plugins too) don't allow inline javascript because of security concerns.

If you want to attach an event handler to the button to do the same without using inline-javascript, do the following:

```
// looks for an element using its ID
var zoomButton = document.getElementById("btnZoomIn");

// the button is now listening for click events
zoomButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {  
  // this function will be called whenever the button is clicked.
  // if you have already written the function, you can also do the following
});

// FncZoomIn will be called whenever the button is clicked
zoomButton.addEventListener("click", FncZoomIn);
```

Comment: It doesn't work if i use extension !
In web page, it works http://imgur.com/J8urNJ4
But in popup page of chrome extension, it didn't work http://imgur.com/COs0V5H
I don't know why ?